# Can not configure FBA(Form Based Authentication) in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013, fba

Can not connect Form Base Authentication(FBA) in SharePoint Server 2013
i tried Configure Form Base Authentication(FBA) in SharePoint Server 2013 and done the following steps.
Here my AD Server name is = adds and ip is (192.168.1.26)

Step 1. Created New WebApplication and Enable Forms Based Authentication (FBA) and give the following values ASP.NET Membership provider name= **LDAPMember** and ASP.NET Role manager name = **LDAPRole**

Step 2.Changed web.config of the web application.
 - Find  entry and Put the below XML directly under  entry.

```
        <add name="LDAPMember" 
        type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, 
        Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
        PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
        server="192.168.1.26" 
        port="389" 
        useSSL="false" 
        userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" 
        userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName" 
        userContainer="OU=SP CONTACTS,DC=ADDS" 
        userObjectClass="person" 
        userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)" 
        scope="Subtree" 
        otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" />



- Find the RoleManager entry and Put the below XML under Providers
   entry.        

    <add name="LDAPRole" 
            type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapRoleProvider, 
            Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
            server="192.168.1.26" 
            port="389" 
            useSSL="false" 
            groupContainer="OU=SP CONTACTS,DC=ADDS" 
            groupNameAttribute="cn" 
            groupNameAlternateSearchAttribute="samAccountName" 
            groupMemberAttribute="member" 
            userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName" 
            dnAttribute="distinguishedName" 
            groupFilter="(ObjectClass=group)" 
            userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)" 
            scope="Subtree" />
```

- Put the below entry in the People Picker Wildcards entry.

```
    <PeoplePickerWildcards>
          <clear />
          <add key="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" value="%" />
        <add key="LDAPMember" value="*"/>
        <add key="LDAPRole" value="*"/>
        </PeoplePickerWildcards>
```

Step 3.Modifying web.config of the Central Administration site.
- Open web.config file of  Central Administration site
- Find the  entry
- Put the following XML directly below it

```
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
                <add name="LDAPMember" 
                 type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
                 server="192.168.1.26" 
                 port="389" 
                 useSSL="false" 
                 userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" 
                 userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName" 
                 userContainer="OU=SP CONTACTS,DC=ADDS" 
                 userObjectClass="person" 
                 userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)" 
                 scope="Subtree" 
                 otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" />
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" > 
          <providers>
            <add name="LDAPRole" 
                 type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapRoleProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
                 server="192.168.1.26" 
                 port="389"
                 useSSL="false"
                 groupContainer="OU=SP CONTACTS,DC=ADDS"
                 groupNameAttribute="cn"
                 groupNameAlternateSearchAttribute="samAccountName"
                 groupMemberAttribute="member"
                 userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName"
                 dnAttribute="distinguishedName"
                 groupFilter="(ObjectClass=group)"
                 userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)"
                 scope="Subtree" />
          </providers>
     </roleManager>
```

- Put the below entry in the People Picker Wildcards entry.

```
    <PeoplePickerWildcards>
          <clear />
          <add key="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" value="%" />
        <add key="LDAPMember" value="*"/>
        <add key="LDAPRole" value="*"/>
        </PeoplePickerWildcards>
```

Step 4.Modifying web.config of the Security Token Service (STS).
- Open the web.config file  of Security Token Service (STS)
- Find the  entry
- Below full entry need to be added directly below  entry

```
        <system.web>
            <membership>
              <providers>
                <add name="LDAPMember" 
                     type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
                     server="192.168.1.26" 
                     port="389" 
                     useSSL="false" 
                     userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" 
                     userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName" 
                     userContainer="OU=SP CONTACTS,DC=ADDS" 
                     userObjectClass="person" 
                     userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)" 
                     scope="Subtree" 
                     otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" />
              </providers>
            </membership>
            <roleManager enabled="true" > 
              <providers>
                <add name="LDAPRole" 
                     type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapRoleProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
                     server="192.168.1.26" 
                     port="389"
                     useSSL="false"
                     groupContainer="OU=SP CONTACTS,DC=ADDS"
                     groupNameAttribute="cn"
                     groupNameAlternateSearchAttribute="samAccountName"
                     groupMemberAttribute="member"
                     userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName"
                     dnAttribute="distinguishedName"
                     groupFilter="(ObjectClass=group)"
                     userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)"
                     scope="Subtree" />
              </providers>
            </roleManager>
          </system.web>
```

Step 5.Add a user policy to the web application
- Go to CA, Application Management, Manage Web Applications
- Highlight the claims based web application

Now here Actual Problems come There will be two entries for same name one of AD and other for LDAP

In my case it will display one entry and its for Active Directory.So Let me know is there anything that i missing?

Again, this is 2013. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!.

Answer (score -1):

```
  connectionUsername=" "
  connectionPassword= " "
```

Comment: Serge you should add some explanation to support your code.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the questions for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.